# Miss something in simple loops

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a range of cell in one sheet I wish copy n times in another sheet:
for n=4 one would have:

```
Input (Sheet1)              Output (Sheet2)
 ABC                           ABC
 DEF                           ABC
 GHI                           ABC
                               ABC
                               DEF
                               DEF
                               DEF
                               DEF
                               GHI
                               GHI
                               GHI
                               GHI
```

What I did is simply:

```
Sub REPLICATE()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim TEMP As String

  For i = 1 To 400
    TEMP = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Cell(i, 1).Value
      For j = 1 To 4
        Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja2").Cell(j, 1) = TEMP
      Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

And I got the error 438. I thought the problem could have been that I use string, but I tried with simple Integer in my Sheet1, and I've gotten the same problem. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `Cells` not `Cell`. In any case, your code won't work because it will overwrite (j restarts at 1 every time). Try this instead (adjust sheet references to suit).

```
Sub REPLICATE()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Sheets` collection returns an `Object`, which means anything you type after accessing it will not give you *IntelliSense* or auto-complete assistance, and VBA will happily compile it, because any call made against the `Object` interface is late-bound and therefore only resolved at run-time.

The solution is to stick to early-bound code and declare a `Worksheet` object. Also, use the `Worksheets` collection if you mean to pull a `Worksheet`, since the `Sheets` collection can give you `Chart` objects (i.e. not all sheets are *worksheets*).

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Workbooks("Libro1").Worksheets("Hoja1")
```

And now when you type `ws.` you'll see that `Cell` is indeed not a member of the `Worksheet` type (hence "Object doesn't support property or method"):

```
For i = 1 To ws.Cells(...)
```

That said if `Workbooks("Libro1")` is `ThisWorkbook` (the book that contains the VBA code), then you should be using the *existing* worksheet object instead.

You get a "free", global-scope `Worksheet` object variable for each `Worksheet` document module in your VBA project - just use it!

```
For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(...)
```

Like [SJR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46568302/1188513) does.

You can rename that global-scope object variable by finding the sheet in the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R), and then changing its `(Name)` property in the *properties* toolwindow (F4). Note, changing the name like this will **not** automatically update your existing code that uses `Sheet1`. If you want to rename and *propagate* the change, you need to *refactor* your code. [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage) can do that for you:

Right-click the worksheet in Rubberduck's *Code Explorer*:

[image: before refactoring]

Supply a new name:

[image: supplying the new name]

Every reference to the old name across the entire code is now updated:

[image: after refactoring]

You can also try performing that refactoring with Ctrl+H "Find/Replace", but that can be tedious, and risks introducing more issues. Rubberduck builds a symbol table for this, so it's much more robust than a simple find & replace.

Comment: Most educative, as ever.

Comment: Thank you for the quality of the explanation and your time, this is so usefull.